# Why are these properties of my objects undefined during a for in loop?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I am trying to figure out why this code won't log the actual property values, and instead just logs undefined over and over, even though I thought I created the property `'random'` in each object and gave it a value with `Math.random()`.

```
var students = [{id:'1'}, {id:'2'}, {id:'3'}, {id:'4'}];


sortStudents(resetRandom(students));

function resetRandom(ary) {
    for (var i = ary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ary[i]['random'] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    };
    return ary
}
```

If I `console.log()` the students array after invoking `resetRandom(students)` the `'random'` property is defined as a number like expected, in each of the objects in the array.  The function below is where the problem occurs when I try to log that property I just get undefined:

```
function sortStudents(ary) {

    for (var i = ary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(var key in ary[i]) {
            if (key === 'random') {
                console.log(ary[key]);
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: It has to be `ary[i].key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 if (key === 'random') {
                console.log(ary[key]);
            }
```

to :

```
 if (key === 'random') {
                console.log(ary[i][key]);
            }
```